# Sitecore administration page to view all pipeline processors

Tags: configuration, pipelines

Is there an administration page to view all pipeline processors that are configured in Sitecore and the order in which they will execute? I'm trying to verify that my custom processor is being inserted into the right place in the Sitecore pipeline but I don't see anything in the Sitecore control panel or the start menu on the Sitecore desktop to facilitate this.

Comment: While I agree, this would be extremely useful, I don't think you could ever determine the order in which pipelines execute. They're not interconnected via configs - code decides to run them.

Comment: @MarkCassidy The order in which the processors execute within the pipeline is determined based on configuration though, right?

Comment: Yes, but only if you assume two things. 1) No processor aborts the pipeline. 2) No processor branches out and executes another pipeline. And 2 is definitely not true, this happens very often even in default configs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes there is. Depends on your Sitecore version but you can use: `/sitecore/admin/pipelines.aspx`

**Sitecore Pipeline Profiler page**

The Sitecore Pipeline Profiler page has been in from Sitecore 7 but is disabled by default.

You enable by renaming the `/App_Config/Include/Sitecore.PipelineProfiling.config.disabled` to remove the `.disabled` extension and setting the `Pipelines.Profiling.Enabled` setting in the file to `true`.

You can also set `Pipelines.Profiling.MeasureCpuTime` setting to true, this gives you additional information.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` page to view the generated Sitecore configuration to verify if you're custom pipeline is inserted into the pipeline and it's position of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `pipelines.aspx` is the page where you can view all pipeline processors.
By default, Pipeline profiling is disabled.

To enable pipeline profiling, add the following key `<add key="env:define" value="Profiling" />` to `Web.config` `<appSettings>` section.

After that go to the `https://{Sitecore Instance}/sitecore/admin/pipelines.aspx` you will get all the pipelines processors.

[image]